# Centering image on css

Tags: html, css, web

I am trying to make my logo center using the following codes..

It is in the header-container.

```
<div class="header-container">
    <div class="header">
    <h2 class="logo">
        <a href="www.www.com" title="scorpia" class="logo">
             <img src="headerbg.jpg" alt="scorpia">
        </a>
    </h2>
    </div>
</div>

.logo {}
.header-container {}
.header {  
    margin:0 auto; 
    padding:0px; 
    text-align:center; 
    position:relative; 
    z-index:10;
}
.header .logo { 
    display:block; 
    text-decoration:none !important; 
}
.header .logo strong { 
    position:relative; 
    top:-999em; 
    left:-999em; 
    width:0; 
    height:0; 
    font-size:0; 
    line-height:0; 
    text-indent:-999em; 
    overflow:hidden; 
}
.header h1.logo, .header h2.logo { 
    margin:0; 
}
```

This is the result I am getting.. As you can see it is a little towards the right [image]

Anyone know how could I fix this?

Comment: What part is the `.header`? You need to post the markup too.

Comment: .header is the white space.. im sorry.. dont know what should i post

Comment: specify width for the `.header` ,`width:1000px` will do for you

Comment: The problem is the image. Just open it alone and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Write your page like this.

You can also do a very convenient vertical centering with `vertical-align:middle;`

html

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
        <div class="header">
            <img class="logo" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ligN.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div id="inner2" style=""></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
}
body {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
#wrapper {
    display:table-cell;
   /* vertical-align:middle;*/
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
#container {
    height:100%; 
    width:70%;
    background:red;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.header {    
    width:90%;
    height:20%;
    background:black;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.logo {width:100%}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TqaBM/

Comment: Thanks for your help! I added some new codes which would probably let you guys understand it easier..

Answer (score 0):

Try something like;

```
.header img {
     display:block;
     margin:0 auto;
     width:100%;
}
```

Ie applying the centering (`margin:0 auto`) to the actual image.

But a jsfiddle of your code would help :)

Comment: What's a jsfiddle? I have no idea what other codes do i have to provide. Hmmm. Any advice?

Comment: How do you center something with `width:100%`?

Comment: Your code doesn't look complete thats all. What container/wrapper is it sitting in? @John without seeing the rest of the code I just assumed it was sitting in a wrapper or container with fixed dimensions.

Comment: I added some new codes...

Comment: To center an image you add (margin:0 auto) to the img { } attribute selector.